# Транслитерация и кавычки

Tags: кавычки, транслитерация

Мы читаем книгу "Транслитерация кириллицей названия книги на иностр. языке" (Название книги на русском языке - перевод), которая написана давно.
Транслитерация... в кавычках, надо ли кавычить перевод в скобках?
Например.
Сочинение аль-Газали «Тахафут ал-фаласифа» (Опровержение философов) было написано...
Или должно быть ("Опровержение философов")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как же без кавычек? Они ж рабочие! Такое же название, только переведённое, о.

*Сочинение аль-Газали «Тахафут ал-фаласифа» («Опровержение философов») было написано...*